# Application crashes with error message even after handling unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

We subscribed unhandled thread exceptions and unhandled exceptions as given below

```
public partial class ICEView : Form
{

    public ICEView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);
        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(OnThreadException);
    }
}
```

Sometimes the application crashes without entering the exception handlers showing an error message as in the link given below. But the error message we got does not have the "Debug" button. What could be the reason for showing the message box.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/winerror.jpg

Comment: Which .NET CLR version in particular? .NET 4.0?

Comment: The CLR version for .NET 3.5 is 2.0

Comment: @Oded: Yes, but I could be considered guilty as my question could have been considered a trick question (asking for CLR then hinting .NET 4.0). Anyway, I was thinking about "state corrupting exceptions", that are no longer caught by `UnhandledException` by default. But since it is not .NET/CLR 4.0 this is irrelevant now.

Comment: @Christian.K - Trying to explain to OP that .NET version and CLR versions are not the same thing...

Comment: The application uses unmanaged code. Will this be due to firing exceptions in unmanaged side?

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the exception handlers in the `Main` method in Program.cs before your form or try adding the exception handlers before the `InitializeComponent` method.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(OnThreadException);
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);

    Application.Run(new ICEView());
}
```